# TransformFeedback binding multiple output buffers

Tags: opengl, glsl, gpgpu, transform-feedback

I'm using the TransformFeedback feature of GL. Is it possible to bind multiple output buffers instead of a single buffer? Assuming I have two output varyings:

```
out vec4 out0;
out vec4 out1;
```

And I have generated two buffer objects for them:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &id0);
glGenBuffers(1, &id1);
```

How can I bind `id0` to `out0` and `id1` to `out1`?

I've tried the `glBindBuffersBase` and `glBindBufferRange`, but seems neither does this.

Comment: Are you using desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: I'm using desktop. Any differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GL_SEPARATE_ATTRIBS` as the `bufferMode` parameter for  `glTransformFeedbackVaryings`, and you'll get one buffer bind point per output. However, note there is a maximum number of transform feedback buffers, so this isn't always going to work if you want to capture lots of outputs concurrently.

Once you've done that then you'll need to bind one buffer `GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER` per transform feedback location.